# Let $K $be a field and $f \in K[x]$. Then there exists a splitting field for $f$ over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Let $K $ be a field and $f \in K[X]$. Then there exists a splitting field for $f$ over $K$.

I don't understand what this means, I think I am interpreting it wrongly.

Take $x^2+1 \in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ then the theorem seems to me to say that there is a splitting field for $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ but clearly it can't split there since the roots of $x^2+1$ are not real.

So it actually saying we can find a field extension $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq L$ such that $L$ is the splitting field? (I think $L$ here would actually be $\Bbb{Q}(i)?$)

Comment: "there exists a splitting field for $f$ over $K$" what are you taking this to mean? $\mathbb Q(i)$ is a splitting field for $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: That is my confusion. I don't understand that sentence? I am taking it to mean that there exists a field extension $L$ over $K$ such that $L$ is a splitting field for $f$ is this right?

Comment: It means there exists an extension for current field that does contain roots to said polynomial.

Comment: okay thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)=x^2+1$ in Extended field of $\mathbb{Q}\,$, therefore
$$f(\alpha)=f(-\alpha)=\alpha^2+1=0$$
on the other hand
$$-\alpha=-(\alpha)$$
as a result
$$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\{a+b\alpha|\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}\cong \frac{{{\mathbb{Q}}}[x]}{({{x}^{2}}+1)}=a+bx+\left\langle {{x}^{2}}+1 \right\rangle$$

Answer (score 0):

the signification of $ L $ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$
is: in an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of  $K$, the field $L$ is the
smallest field containing K (as minimum degree of $L$ over $K$)
and included in $\Omega$, in which $f$ split  completely (that is
has all roots in $L$)